# boost regex capture group and replace

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to expand a CamelCase string this way: `CamelCase` >> `Camel Case`, using boost.

```
string Utils::ExpandCamelCase(string & str)
{
    static boost::regex camelCaseExpandRegex = boost::regex(R"(\B[A-Z]+?(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])|\B[A-Z]+?(?=[^A-Z]))");
    string result = boost::regex_replace(str, camelCaseExpandRegex, "  $1");
    return result;
}
```

As you see I am trying to capture first group, which should be the upper letter of each word (excluding first one), and to replace it with a space plus that group.

Something is wrong since "ExpandCamelCasePlease" turns into "Expand amel ase lease".

Trying variations I suspect that I am not capturing the group as I should.

What changes do I need to make to expand correctly camel case inserting spaces before capital letters?

Comment: https://regex101.com/debugger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`.

It uses lookbehind `(?<=[a-z])`, to see if what is behind is lowercase letter and it looks ahead (`(?=[A-Z])`) to see if what's ahead it uppercase letter.

Then just replace it with space .

[Demo](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
string Utils::ExpandCamelCase(string & str)
{
static boost::regex camelCaseExpandRegex = boost::regex(R"([A-Z][^ ]+?)(?=[A-Z]|$)");
string result = boost::regex_replace(str, camelCaseExpandRegex, "  $1");
return result;
```

}

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/SB4nEi/2)